# Given $g(n) = \omega(f(n))$, then $g(n) + f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

I have a proof but I don't know if the assumptions I did are correct.

I know that $g(n)$ dominates $f(n)$, since $g(n) = \omega(f(n))$ and I did the assumption that $g(n) + f(n) = g(n)$. So, by reflexivity, $g(n) = \Omega (g(n))$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Assuming $f$ is non-negative, $g(n) + f(n) \geq g(n)$, and so $g(n) + f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$. We don't even have to use the assumption $g(n) = \omega(f(n))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler proof. Assuming (as is usually the case) that $f$ is non-negative, we get $g(n) + f(n) \geq g(n)$, which implies that $g(n) + f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$. There is no need to assume anything.

If we know that $g(n) = \Omega(f(n))$, we can conclude further than $g(n) + f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$. And if $g(n) = \omega(f(n))$ then $g(n) + f(n) \sim g(n)$.